# Check for an array of words in a string in php

Tags: php

I have a special list of spam words that are in an array.
When a user submits a string text, I want to know if it contains these words.
How do I do this?
I wrote this code

```
$my_words = 'buy;sell;shop;purchase';
$array_words = explode(';' ,$my_words); //convert the list to an array
$input_text = 'we can sell your products'; //user will input this text

foreach($array_words as $word){
    if(strpos($input_text  ,$word) !== false)   return 'You can't use from this text';
}
```

But if I have many special words, the foreach slows down the execution speed.

Comment: try with regex, put your words into regex and check with OR condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may form a regex alternation based on your semicolon-delimited string, and then search for that:

```php
$my_words = 'buy;sell;shop;purchase';
$regex = '/\b(?:' . str_replace(";", "|", $my_words) . ")\b/";
$input_text = 'we can sell your products';
if (preg_match($regex, $input_text)) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
else {
    echo "NO MATCH";
}
```

Here is an explanation of the (exact) regex built and used above:

```
/\b(?:buy|sell|shop|purchase)\b/

\b            match the start of a word, which is either
(?:
    buy
    |         OR
    sell
    |         OR
    shop
    |         OR
    purchase
)
\b            match the end of a word
```

Comment: can you tell me more about the regex? what  '/\b' and '?:' mean?

Comment: Thank you, and regex can work for Arabic letters without problem?

Comment: Yes, PHP regex can be made to work with any UTF-8 language (but that's not exactly what you asked above).

Comment: I checked this code, it have a little different with strpos. regex not work for spaces.
for example: `$input_text = 'we can sellyour products'; ` , the regex will show NO MATCH but strpos will show MATCH

Comment: @Learner231 Well if you just want to match _substrings_, then remove the `\b` from the regex pattern.  But, keep in mind that by doing this the word `seller` would then become a match for the keyword `sell`.  Is that the logic you really want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *|* as word separator and then use regular expression to check

```
$my_words = 'buy|sell|shop|purchase';
$input_text = 'we can sell your products'; //user will input this text
return preg_match('#(?:'.$my_words.')#i', $input_text);
```

Use *i* flag to disable case sensitivity

Comment: Code changed after my comment. But it still checks for containing, not a word. `'we cansell your products'` <-- "cansell" will also return true, which should return false.